# Clear cache of form's field

Tags: asp.net, caching

I want to clear textbox's cache.Suppose you have logged into gmail again if you will sigout and log in, testbox for Username show an intellisense kind of thing.How to stop that ?

Answer (score 6):

```
<input type="text" name="ac" autocomplete="off" />
```

Source: http://www.w3.org/Submission/web-forms2/

Comment: note that in some browsers (ie and firefox for starters) this won't clear an existing cache (but it will stop other people from ever creating the cache)

Answer (score 1):

You should set the AutoCompleteType property to Disabled.

Check [this msdn page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.autocompletetype.aspx) for details.

Answer (score 0):

You can set attribute 'autocomplete="off" ' at form tag as bellow:

```
<form name="login_form" id ="id_login_form" method="post" action="LoginServlet" autocomplete="off">
```